Equivalence between $A^{-1}$ adjointable and $A^*$ invertible
I’m having trouble giving a proof of the following proposition:
Let $A$ be an unbounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. If $A$ is invertibile, then:
$$
A^* \text{ is invertibile} \iff A^{-1} \text{ is adjointable}
$$
where $A^*$ is the adjoint operator of $A$. If this holds, then:
$$
(A^*)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^*
$$
For context, this proposition comes right after the introduction of the chapter about unbounded operators, which are being characterised by their graph. It’s at the end of my course in elements of functional analysis.
I’ve seen this proof, but it concerns $A$ as a bounded operator.

What's the meaning of "adjointable" in this context? The adjoint always exists, even though its domain might be trivial.

@Martin Argerami As far as what I’ve been taught in this course, the adjoint only exists when the operator is bounded. When it’s not, it is adjointable when $V\Gamma_A^\perp$ is a graph, where we define $V(x,y)=(y,-x)$ on $\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}$ and $\Gamma_A$ is the graph of $A$, meaning the set: ${(x,Ax)\in\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H} : x\in dom(A)}$

Ok, so your definition of adjointable  is  "densely defined".

@MartinArgerami Yes! The corollary to this is precisely that an operator is adjointable if and only if it has a densely defined domain.

As clarified in the comments, we use the definition that $A$ is adjointable if $V(\Gamma_A)^\perp$ is the graph of an operator, where $V$ is the map $(x,y)\longmapsto (y,-x)$.
Claim. $A$ is adjointable if and only if it is densely defined. $\def\d{\mathcal D}$ (proof at the end) $\def\ran{\operatorname{ran}}$
Suppose that $A^*$ is invertible. This implies by the claim that $A$ is densely defined, and that there exists $C:\ran A^*\to\d(A^*)$ with $CA^*=I_{\d(A^*)}$ and $A^*C=I_{\ran A^*}$. Let $v\in (\ran A)^\perp$. We have $\langle v,Az\rangle=0$ for all $z\in\d(A)$; hence $\langle 0,z\rangle=0=\langle v,Az\rangle$ for all $z\in\d(A)$. This implies by $(*)$ that $(v,0)\in \Gamma_{A^*}$ and $A^*v=0$. Then $v=CA^*v=0$. Thus $\ran A^\perp=\{0\}$, so $\ran A$ is dense. This is the domain of $A^{-1}$, so $A^{-1}$ is densely defined, hence adjointable by the claim.
Conversely, suppose that $A^{-1}$ is adjointable. This means that $\ran A$ is dense. Let $x\in\ker A^*$. Then $A^*x=0$ and $x\in\d(A^*)$, which means that $(x,0)\in V(\Gamma_A)^\perp$. By $(*)$, this is $\langle x,Az\rangle=\langle 0,z\rangle=0$ for all $z\in\d(A)$; so $x\in(\ran A)^\perp=\{0\}$. So $x=0$ and $A^*$ is injective. So $A^*$ is invertible onto its range. Now let $w\in(\ran A^*)^\perp$. This implies that for $(x,y)\in\Gamma_{A^*}$ we have
$$
\langle (0,w),(x,y)\rangle=\langle 0,x\rangle+\langle w,y\rangle=\langle 0,x\rangle=0. 
$$
Thus $(0,w)\in(\Gamma_{A^*})^\perp=(V(\Gamma_A)^\perp)^\perp=V\overline{\Gamma_A}$ (note that $V$ is a unitary so it preserves orthogonality). This means that $(0,w)\in\Gamma_A$, so $w=A0=0$. Hence $\ran A^*$ is dense.
When $A^*$ is invertible (and $A^{-1}$ is densely defined/adjointable), for $w\in\d(A^{-1})=\ran A$ we have $w=Ax$ for some $x\in\d(A)$ and for $y\in\ran A^*$ we have $y=A^*v$. Then
$$
\langle A^{-1}w,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*v\rangle=\langle Ax,v\rangle=\langle w,(A^*)^{-1}y\rangle. 
$$
Then $(A^*)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^*$.

Proof of the Claim. We have
\begin{align}\tag{$*$}
(x,y)\in V(\Gamma_A)^\perp&
\iff
(-y,x)\in(\Gamma_A)^\perp\\[0.2cm]
&\iff
\langle x,Az\rangle=\langle y,z\rangle,\ \forall z\in\d(A).
\end{align}
Suppose that $A$ is densely defined. If $(x,y),(x,v)\in V(\Gamma_A)^\perp$, then for any $z\in\d(A)$,
$$
\langle y,z\rangle=\langle x,Az\rangle=\langle v,z\rangle. 
$$
Then $y=v$ and $V(\Gamma_A)^\perp$ is the graph of an operator; thus $A$ is adjointable.
Conversely, suppose that $A$ is not densely defined. Let $w\in \d(A)^\perp$ be nonzero. We have
$$
\langle w,z\rangle=0=\langle 0,Az\rangle\ \text{ for all } z\in \d(A).
$$
Hence $(0,w)\in V(\Gamma_A)^\perp$, showing that it cannot be the graph of an operator. Thus $A$ is not adjointable. $\Box$
